# Can SSRS be installed on SQL Server 2014 Web Edition?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2014

I've been told this is possible, but my searches have yield nothing on this possibility. Has anyone done this or know of someone who has?

I know this is a strange question and I know the obvious answer is upgrade to Standard, but that's not an option I'm currently allowed :(

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You mean Web edition?

Comment: Yes, sorry fat fingered that.

Comment: Why would you need Standard? Is there a corporate reason a simple Express Version could not work? It has SSRS. See [Editions and Components MSDN](MSDN.Microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144275.aspx)

Comment: Yes mdf file limitations on Express.

Answer (score 0):

[Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx)

[image]

[image]